# jQuery variable trouble

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm trying to load in some content with the .load() function, here's my code.

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $('.spotlight').append('<div class="caption"></div>');
    $('.spotlight .caption').hover(function () { 
         $(this).animate({ top : '-=50px' }, 150)}, function () {
         $(this).animate({ top : '+=50px' }, 150)}
    );

    $('.caption').load($(this).parent().data('who')+'.html');

});
```

but in the HTML I have

```
<div class="spotlight" who="student">
      <img src="sga_small.jpg" />
</div>


<div class="spotlight" who="staff">
    <img src="sga_small.jpg" />
</div>
```

But it tries to load in undefined.html. How would I go about fixing this?
Here's a link to the page http://www.coralspringshigh.org/demo/

Comment: Can you give us the whole event that you are calling `.load()` from?  Its hard to know what `this` is without the context of that function...

Comment: can you paste complete HTML with the element which has caption class

Comment: Sorry about that, added the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thought, you should be using `data-who="student"` instead of just `who`, that way you can use `$(this).parent().data('who')+'.html'`

Now that you've updated to include more of the code, the flaw is more obvious.  `this` in that context is actually `window` because you are inside of the `$(window).load()` handler.  Try doing something like this instead:

```
// fires on document ready, not quite window load, but better:
$(function() {
  $('.spotlight').each(function() {
    var spot = $( this ),
        caption = $("<div class='caption'></div>").appendTo(spot);

    caption.load( spot.data('who') + '.html' );
    spot.hover(function() {
      caption.animate({ top : '-=50px' }, 150)
    }, function () {
      caption.animate({ top : '+=50px' }, 150)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Also I don't think the `who` attribute is valid on any element.  data-{anything here}, however, is.

Comment: @Koalatea - You need to give us more info in the original question - see the comments please....

Comment: Ahh, I just realized it was 'window.load()', that was a stupid mistake by me. but it still tries to load undefined.html, except instead of trying to load it once, it fails twice, so at least that's better.

Comment: @Koalatea did you switch to using the `data-who` attribute in the HTML instead of just `who` ???

Comment: Me being an idiot, forgot to do that part. Thanks for putting up with me! Working good now.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are this is returning undefined:

```
$(this).parent().attr('who')
```

Make sure that this parent has a value in the attribute who.

Comment: It does, but theres two parents with attribute who, making it undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.caption').each(function() {
                       $(this).load($(this).parent().attr('who') + '.html');
                   });
```

Comment: The problem with that is that it loads both .captions with the same file